# Firefox 8.0 doesn't resize content like other browsers

Tags: html, css, firefox, resize

I'm making a page to scale down to fairly small browser sizes, including on desktops.  I've got it down for pretty much every browser but firefox; it just doesn't make the content smaller the same way as other browsers.

Say I have a simple page like this:

```
<body>
    <div style="width:auto; max-width:500px; margin:20px;background-color:black;"> Some filler text </div>
</body>
```

If you try that in any browser but firefox, when you resize the window to smaller than 540px, the div gets smaller, as you would expect.  But in firefox, it does no such thing. At least not in 8.0.  It resizes the div a tiny amount and then lets it extend off the window, without even leaving a scrollbar.

Is there any way around this behavior?

EDIT:  I've reproduced this is on older versions of firefox as well, but I found something odd.  When I said it resizes the div a tiny amount, here's what happens: the body of the page stays at 367px width.  Two different versions of firefox, two versions of windows, the same number.

Comment: Does "width: 100%" do the same thing?

Comment: Essentially, yes it does, though using auto instead of 100% makes the browser take into account margins, padding, etc.  E.g. if the browser is 500px wide and the div has 100% width and 20px margins , the page will be 40px too wide for the browser.  With auto, the div should resize to 460px to account for the margins.

Comment: I do not observe this problem in Firefox 8.0.1 on OSX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're running into is that in Firefox depending on the exact themes or extensions in use as you resize the browser window the browser content area may not resize (because, for example, the various buttons on the widest toolbar impose a minimum width on that content area due to the way the user interface is laid out).

This is why you see the body not changing size: the CSS viewport itself is not changing size.  If your page had a vertical scrollbar, you'd see that scrollbar disappear off the right edge of the window, just like parts of the browser UI itself disappear.

You can work around this with enough toolbar customization (e.g. remove everything from the toolbars) if you just need this for testing.  On the other hand if you just need this for testing you can probably jut load the site in an iframe which you then size however you want...

Comment: Yep this is true.  To me it seems it might be a better idea to base the size of the content area entirely on window size rather than on the toolbars, which vary wildly between different users, and also have the potential to be half-hidden if the window is resized to be narrow (though it doesn't have to be too narrow if the toolbars are big).  Plus, the way it is now, even the horizontal scrollbar gets hidden.

Comment: Sure, that resizing behavior is a bug in the Firefox front-end code.  It's been fixed a few times, but keeps reappearing when someone else rearranges the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to say something about your comment regarding "width: auto" vs "width: 100%" but I can't comment yet...

You can set "width: 100%" and make it account for padding and borders by also setting "box-sizing: border-box" - you'll need to use the vendor prefixes I believe -moz- and -webkit-. Not sure if it will solve you problem, but it's good to know - maybe try it out and see what happens.